# How is an insert query in PostgreSQL different from an insert query in Oracle?

Tags: php, sql, oracle, postgresql

How is an insert query in PostgreSQL is different from an insert query in Oracle? Not in terms of syntax, but how these database languages treat insert statements. It is said that you always have timeouts on your insertion queries in PostgreSQL.

Why is this so?

Comment: "It is said that always have timeouts on your insertion queries on postgre." Is it? By who? How often? What was their reasoning? I'm not saying it's necessarily a bad idea to have timeouts on all statements but that applies to any database surely? Oh, and it isn't called "postgre" anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

`INSERT` behaves virtually the same in Oracle and PostgreSQL.

PostgreSQL `INSERT`s don't time out by default. An `INSERT` should normally be very fast, unless it is blocked by a lock. In that case, you can use `lock_timeout` or `statement_timeout`, but as I said, these are set to infinite by default.

The only difference I have encountered is that Oracle sometimes throws a serialization error during `INSERT` if you are using the `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level, but that is more sloppy implementation than by design (they were too lazy to handle index page splits and delayed segment creation in a less disruptive fashion).